# How do I run this check even at all times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check if a file has a new line added to it but the check does not do what its supposed to do.

```
 while True:
    with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
        currentLines = len(file.readlines())
        if currentLines != totalLines:
            totalLines = currentLines
            get_latest_message()
            print(totalLines)
        else:
            myMessage = input("type a message: ")
            send_message(myMessage)
```

The program is supposed to use get_latest_message() if the text file is edited but this does not work because the check is only executed after you send a message because of the way the loop is structured, and because get_latest_message() only prints the latest message (yours since you just sent it) and skips over any sent in between.

Basically, I want to run the above code even while stopped at the `myMessage = input("type a message: ")` part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying putting each seperate component of the program in seperate threads using the `threading` library. You could loop through and check if any new text was added to the file in one thread, while the other thread could be checking whether the user input any text, and writing it to the file.